# remove bracket and its content in python

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, preprocessor

I have implemented an emotion analysis classification using lstm method. I have already train my model and saved it. I have load the train model and I am doing the classification part where I am saving it in a dataframe. I need to remove brackets along with its content I will show you below.

here are my codes:

```
 hotelname = []
sentimentanalysis = []

for item in selection1:
    name = item['name']
    hotelname.append(name)
    print (name)
```

the output is as follows:

```
Mystik Lifestyle (Save 34%)
Chalets Chamarel (Adults Only)
Andrea Lodge (Save 18%)
Hibiscus Beach Resort & Spa (Save 18%)
Lagoon Attitude (Adults Only)
Ocean V Hotel (Adults Only)
```

but I want my output to be like this::

```
Mystik Lifestyle 
Chalets Chamarel 
Andrea Lodge 
Hibiscus Beach Resort & Spa 
Lagoon Attitude 
Ocean V Hotel
```

can someone please tell me what do I need to add in my codes please guys.

Comment: one hack is to split by '(' and take the first element (if any)

Comment: i have not understood madam..can you please explain?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it by using the simple String method called **.split()**.
Look at the code below:

```
elements = ['Mystik Lifestyle (Save 34%)',
'Chalets Chamarel (Adults Only)',
'Andrea Lodge (Save 18%)',
'Hibiscus Beach Resort & Spa (Save 18%)',
'Lagoon Attitude (Adults Only)',
'Ocean V Hotel (Adults Only)']

for element in elements:
    without_text_after_unwanted_character = element.split('(')[0] 
    # This will get everything before the '(' as we splitted
    print(without_text_after_unwanted_character)

# If you want to create a new list the new values, you can do:
clean_list = [x.split('(')[0] for x in elements]

for clean_text in clean_list:
    print(clean_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use `re` module for that following way:

```
import re
def clean(n):
    return re.sub(r'\s\(.*\)','',n)
```

then:

```
name = clean(item['name'])
```

instead of

```
name = item['name']
```

Note that I use so-called raw-string as first argument of re.sub and also remove whitespace (`\s`) before bracket and its content. Note that `(` and `)` needs to be escaped as they have special meaning in patterns (hence leading backslashs).

Comment: It is still the same  sir

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def remove_bracket(text):
    x = re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", text)[:-1]
    return x
```

---

```
cleaned_text = remove_bracket(name)
hotelname.append(cleaned_text)
```

**edit:**

```
li = ['Mystik Lifestyle (Save 34%)',
'Chalets Chamarel (Adults Only)',
'Andrea Lodge (Save 18%)',
'Hibiscus Beach Resort & Spa (Save 18%)',
'Lagoon Attitude (Adults Only)',
'Ocean V Hotel (Adults Only)']

for i in li:
    cleaned_text = remove_bracket(i)
    print(cleaned_text)
```

**output:**

```
Mystik Lifestyle
Chalets Chamarel
Andrea Lodge
Hibiscus Beach Resort & Spa
Lagoon Attitude
Ocean V Hotel
```

Comment: It is still the same madam

Comment: print your hotelname

Comment: still the same madam

Comment: please share the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209219/discussion-between-pygirl-and-nedisha).

Answer (score -1):

You try this below code:

```
hotelname = []
sentimentanalysis = []

for item in selection1:
    name = item['name'].split('(')[0].strip()
    hotelname.append(name)
    print (name)
```